# Will Ubuntu work with my Dell Inspiron 640m with minimal driver issues?

Tags: dell

This would be my first time installing Ubuntu and I am looking for some advice on if my laptop configuration (2GB, Core 2 Duo, Inspiron 640m) would be good enough. Currently it runs Windows 7. Will Ubuntu have problems finding drivers for such an old laptop configuration?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu ISO are Live CD/DVDs, which means, you can try it yourself before even installing it on your system. The system boots from the CD and you can perform any task, though the task that can be performed is limited. This is the best way for you to determine if you laptop can actually run Ubuntu. And in case of issues you can always Google or ask for resolution here at askubuntu. I am sure the experts will definitely help you out.

Comment: I think your hardware will be good enough for Ubuntu. The way to check how well it will perform is to try the live DvD/USB; select "Try Ubuntu" when you boot the media. If things work on live, then they should work after installing. You probably will not have to install any driver. Everything should be baked into Ubuntu by now.

Comment: Yes, I installed Ubuntu and it works good. The "Try Ubuntu" option is really helpful in making the decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work well in your PC. I have tested Ubuntu in different machines and virtual machines with even lesser configurations that you have. All of them have worked well for me. Try with the live CD if you want.

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu is working well with my laptop configuration. I had issues with configuring Ethernet and WiFi drivers initially but I was able to find the solution from this forum.